# running Macro's in Excel Workbooks stored in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am new to Sharepoint i am trying to upload a workbook with macros in it on sharepoint. I am not able to run the macros directly on the sharepoint but have to check out and run it. any and all help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

When you open an Excel workbook that's saved on SharePoint in the browser there will be a limited number of features available to you. One of the things you can't do is run macros. This is by design.

You will have to open the workbook using Excel installed on your local machine to run any macros.

[See here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6) for official confirmation of this from Microsoft, which says:

> Excel macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm)
>   A workbook in this format can be opened but macros do not run in a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

With the reference to Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel, you can't run Macros on SharePoint Excel online.

However, if you actually mean you have uploaded the .xlsm file to a document library then you should be able to open the file and provided you have responded to the prompts correctly then the macros should be enabled and function.

One of these is to enable content followed by do you want to make this a trusted document, once you've passed this the file will open without prompting.

So if you are experiencing issues you will need to check the settings under File, Options and Trust Center to see what may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem in Word.  As it turns out, you have to "Enable All Macros" in the Trust Center.